# How to copy-paste, and cut-paste file or folder in java?

Tags: java, swing, copy, paste

I made a desktop app in java with netbeans platform. In my app I want to give separate copy-paste and cut-paste option of file or folder.

So how can I do that? I tried `Files.copy(new File("D:\\Pndat").toPath(),new File("D:\\212").toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING);`. But I don't get the exact output.

If there any other option then suggest me.

Comment: so you want to copy a file one folder from another folder using swing application ? update your code in question so can check what you've tried and where is the issue

Comment: Which part are you not able to do? Selecting the file/directory? Extracting the selected file/directory name? Copying to Clipboard?

Comment: @TJ- i don't know that how to use ClipBoard for copy, cut and paste in java.Have you any example of clipboard?

Comment: @vels4j i upadate what i had done . but that code make folder of 212 name in D: drive but it not copy Pndat folder into 212 folder. So how can do that in java?

Comment: you need to copy entire folder ?

Comment: @vels4j but how to copy entire folder and paste it? have you any idea about that ? then suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html) from apache io and do `FileUtils.copyDirectory(sourceDir, destDir);`

**You can also do the following file operations**

- writing to a file
- reading from a file
- make a directory including parent directories
- copying files and directories
- deleting files and directories
- converting to and from a URL
- listing files and directories by filter and extension
- comparing file content
- file last changed date

[Download link](http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi) for apache i/o jar.

Answer (score 4):

In case of "cut-paste" you can use `renameTo()` like this:

```
File source = new File("////////Source path");
File destination = new File("//////////destination path");

if (!destination.exists()) {
    source.renameTo(destination);
}
```

In case of "copy-paste" you need to read in Input and Output stream.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question relates to using the system clipboard for copying a file specified in a Java app and using the OS "Paste" function to copy the file to a folder.  Here is a short instructional example that will show you how to add a single file to the OS clipboard for later doing an OS "Paste" function.  Tweak as necessary and add error/exception checking as needed.

As a secondary, this code also places the file name on the clipboard so you can paste the file name into document editors.

```
package com.example.charles.clipboard;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaToSystemClipboard {

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final File fileOut = new File("someFileThatExists");
    putFileToSystemClipboard(fileOut);

}

public static void putFileToSystemClipboard(final File fileOut) throws Exception {
    final Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    final ClipboardOwner clipboardOwner = null;

    final Transferable transferable = new Transferable() {
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(final DataFlavor flavor) {
            return false;
        }
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor, DataFlavor.stringFlavor };
        }
        public Object getTransferData(final DataFlavor flavor) {
            if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
                final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(fileOut.getAbsolutePath());
                return list;
            }
            if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                return fileOut.getAbsolutePath();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    clipboard.setContents(transferable, clipboardOwner);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write things by yourself using **FileOutputStream** and **FileInputStream** or you can used **Apache Camel**.